# Unable to retrieve plain text, pako.ungzip(message) is throwing an Exception: incorrect header check

Tags: typescript, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have a service(written in java stack) which will encrypt & compress string text and send to a cloud service(in Typescript). The encrypted messages are then decompressed & decrypted to be process it further at cloud.

At cloud, messages are sent on an Eventhub and read using Azure function-eventhub trigger, functions are based on programing model V4 in typescript.

**Encryption (in java):**

```
 private static byte[] compress(String str) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream obj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
    gzip.write(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    gzip.close();
    return obj.toByteArray();
}
```

**Decryption at Azure function eventhub trigger (in typescript):**

```
app.eventHub('EventTrigger', {
  connection: 'connectionString',
  eventHubName: 'eventHubName',
  consumerGroup: 'cg',
  cardinality: 'one',
  extraOutputs: [Output],
  extraInputs: [cosmosInput],
  handler: EventTrigger
});

export async function EventTrigger(message: any, context: InvocationContext): Promise<void> {
  const mh: Handler = new Handler();
  const deviceMessage = mh.decompressBuf(message, context);
  .....
  ....

}

export class Handler {

  decompressBuf(message: string, context?: InvocationContext): MessageObj {
    const decodedMessage=Buffer.from(message);  
    return this.decom(new Uint8Array(decodedMessage) , context);
  }

  decom(message: Uint8Array, context?: InvocationContext): MessageObj {
    let resultGZipArray = pako.ungzip(message);
    var dec:TextDecoderLite = new TextDecoderLite('utf-8');
    const text= dec.decode(resultGZipArray);       
    return JSON.parse(text) as MessageObj;
  }
}
```

Encrypted message which arrives in function is as below,

[encrypted message looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v8xo.png)

Error as below,

```
[2024-01-08T08:57:11.082Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.EventTrigger. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: incorrect header check
Stack: Error: incorrect header check
    at t.ensureErrorType (C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js:2:29312)
    at C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js:2:45931
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at a (C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js:2:44362)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5).
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure that the encoding used during compression and decoding is consistent. In your Java code, you are using `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` when compressing the string. Make sure to use the same encoding when decoding in TypeScript.
- Add more logging to your TypeScript function to display the raw compressed data and other pertinent information before attempting decompression.

**Output before decoding:**

```
import { AzureFunction, Context } from  "@azure/functions"

  

const eventHubTrigger: AzureFunction = async  function (context: Context, eventHubMessages: any[]): Promise<void> {

context.log(`Eventhub trigger function called for message array ${eventHubMessages}`);

eventHubMessages.forEach((message, index) => {

context.log(`Processed message ${message}`);

});

};

  

export  default eventHubTrigger;
```

[image]
**Output after decoding:**

The sample code below is for messages received in the Event Hub, which are base64-encoded, compressed using Gzip, and have content expected to be in JSON format.

```
import { AzureFunction, Context } from "@azure/functions";
import * as pako from 'pako';

const eventHubTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, eventHubMessages: any[]): Promise<void> {
    context.log(`Eventhub trigger function called for message array ${eventHubMessages}`);
    
    eventHubMessages.forEach((message, index) => {
        context.log(`Processing message ${message}`);
        
        const mh: Handler = new Handler();
        const deviceMessage = mh.decompressBuf(message, context);

        // Your further processing logic here with 'deviceMessage'
        if (deviceMessage) {
            context.log(`Device message: ${JSON.stringify(deviceMessage)}`);

            // Continue with your processing logic, e.g., storing in a database, triggering other functions, etc.
        } else {
            context.log.warn('Skipping processing due to empty device message.');
        }
    });
};

class Handler {
    decompressBuf(message: string, context?: Context): any {
        try {
            const decodedMessage = Buffer.from(message, 'base64'); // Assuming the message is base64 encoded
            return this.decompress(new Uint8Array(decodedMessage), context);
        } catch (error) {
            context.log.error(`Error decoding message: ${error}`);
            throw error;
        }
    }

    private decompress(message: Uint8Array, context?: Context): any {
        try {
            if (message.length === 0) {
                context.log.warn('Empty message received. Skipping decompression.');
                return null; // or handle accordingly
            }

            let resultGZipArray = pako.ungzip(message);
            const text = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(resultGZipArray);

            return JSON.parse(text);
        } catch (error) {
            context.log.error(`Error during decompression: ${error}`);
            throw error;
        }
    }
}

export default eventHubTrigger;
```

[image]

**v4:**

```js
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
const pako = require('pako');

app.eventHub('eventHubTrigger1', {
    connection: 'RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB',
    eventHubName: 'sampath',
    cardinality: 'many',
    handler: async (messages, context) => {
        context.log(`Event hub function processed ${messages.length} messages`);
        
        for (const message of messages) {
            context.log('Processing message:', message);
            
            try {
                const deviceMessage = decompressBuf(message, context);
                
                if (deviceMessage) {
                    context.log(`Device message: ${JSON.stringify(deviceMessage)}`);
                    // Continue with your processing logic, e.g., storing in a database, triggering other functions, etc.
                } else {
                    context.log('Skipping processing due to empty device message.');
                }
            } catch (error) {
                context.log(`Error processing message: ${error}`);
            }
        }
    }
});

function decompressBuf(message, context) {
    try {
        const decodedMessage = Buffer.from(message, 'base64'); // Assuming the message is base64 encoded
        return decompress(new Uint8Array(decodedMessage), context);
    } catch (error) {
        context.log(`Error decoding message: ${error}`);
        throw error;
    }
}

function decompress(message, context) {
    try {
        if (message.length === 0) {
            context.log('Empty message received. Skipping decompression.');
            return null; // or handle accordingly
        }

        let resultGZipArray = pako.ungzip(message);
        const text = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(resultGZipArray);

        return JSON.parse(text);
    } catch (error) {
        context.log(`Error during decompression: ${error}`);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @sampath for the response.

The sample you shared works fine with function runtime V3 and below, it used work for us as well. As we are planning to upgrade to runtime version V4 and "dataType" in function.json is no more in use, the decoding is not working correctly.

The input message is in some unknown characters, attaching the message which arrives in function in the initial question for your reference.

Comment: good that it working with  V3.  I will test with v4 and update u.

Comment: @mshu update with v4